# Flutter Google maps not reloading after changing markers

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-markers

I'm working with the google map widget, when I render the map for the first time with static markers it displays all the markers, but when I get the data from API and try to add new markers to the map, it won't display them.
below the code that i'm using :

```
class Map extends StatefulWidget {
  final Position initialPosition;
  final List<Marker> allSitesMarkers;
  final List<Site> placesSite;
  final List<String> mapMarkersCategories;
  const Map(this.initialPosition, this.allSitesMarkers, this.placesSite,
      this.mapMarkersCategories,
      {Key key})
      : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MapState();
}

class MapState extends State<Map> {
  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  String currentCategoryFilter;
  bool filtred = false;
  Set<Marker> _markers = Set();

  List<Marker> markersToShow;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    refreshMarkers();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: (widget.placesSite.isNotEmpty)
          ? Stack(
              children: [
                GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
                      target: LatLng(36.798, 10.1717), zoom: 15),
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  myLocationEnabled: true,
                  markers: _markers,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    controller.setMapStyle(
                        '[ //... ]');

                    _controller.complete(controller);
                  },
                ),
                _chips()
              ],
            )
          : const NoListMap(),
    );
  }


  Widget _chips() {
    //..
  }

  filterSites(String category) {
    setState(() {
      _markers.clear();
      filtred = true;
      markersToShow = widget.allSitesMarkers
          .where((element) => element.infoWindow.title == category)
          .toList();
    });
    refreshMarkers();
  }

  refreshMarkers() {
    if (filtred) {
      setState(() {
        _markers.clear();
        _markers.addAll(markersToShow);
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        _markers.clear();
        _markers.addAll(widget.allSitesMarkers);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using:
Flutter 2.10.2
Dart 2.16.1
google_maps_flutter : 2.0.9

Answer (score 4):

Your `_markers` is a `Set`, and in `setState` you use `clear` and `addAll` to empty it and to add new items to the set. But the value of `_markers` does not change when you do so, therefore it will not trigger a rebuild.

This happens because `_markers` holds a **reference** to the `Set` (like lists, objects etc.).

You need to assign a new value to `_markers` to trigger a rebuild, for example:

```
setState(() {
  _markers = markersToShow.toSet();
});
```

This will actually change the reference kept in `_markers`.

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your solution, actually after calling `setState()` and changing `_markers`  value it's triggering rebuild but nothing changes in the map.

Comment: @AhmedNezhi You mean after assigning a complete new `Set` to `_markers` as suggested in my answer?

Comment: Yes, after assigning a new `Set` to the `_markers`, still the markers don't change.

Comment: That is strange, if you share updated relevant code, I will have a look at it.

Comment: this is the full code [link](https://gist.github.com/ahmednezhi/4e954808921b38d02d50e2d9ac294bf2)

Comment: marker has been updated on the basis of new coordinates

Comment: Actually, the problem was related to the list of markers, all the markers had the same ID, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good to hear, you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I Did to update the posistion

```
setState(() {
    mapController.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(widget.siteDetails?.location?.lat ?? 8.5555187,
                widget.siteDetails?.location?.long ?? 76.8836149),
            zoom: 11)));
    markers = <Marker>[
      Marker(
          markerId: const MarkerId('MarkId'),
          position: LatLng(widget.siteDetails?.location?.lat ?? 0,
              widget.siteDetails?.location?.long ?? 0),
          infoWindow: InfoWindow.noText)
    ];
  });
```